# Why does this code make my Python interpreter hang?

Tags: python

I had an identical problem with my other laptop, which led me to get this new one (new in the NBC after Friends sense) -- the interpreter would hang on some kind of nested iteration, and even freeze up and/or go berserk if left to its own devices.  In this case, I CTRL+C'd after about five seconds.  The interpreter said it stopped at some line in the while loop, different each time, indicating that it was working but at a slooooooooooow pace.  Some test print statements seemed to show some problem with the iteration controls (the counter and such).

Is it a CPU problem, or what?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

# script is a useless dummy variable, setting captures the setting (enc or dec), steps captures the number of lines.
script, setting, steps = sys.argv

# Input handling bloc.
if setting not in ('enc', 'dec'):
    sys.exit("First command line thing must either be 'enc' or 'dec'.")

try:
    steps = int(steps)
except:
    sys.exit("Second command line thing must be convertable to an integer.")

# Input string here.
string_to_convert = raw_input().replace(' ', '').upper()

if setting == 'enc':
    conversion_string = ''

    counter = 0
    while len(conversion_string) < len(string_to_convert):
        for char in string_to_convert:
            if counter == steps:
                conversion_string += char
                counter = 0
            counter += 1
        steps -= 1

print(conversion_string)
```

Comment: sample input and output?

Comment: Sample output: "DERPDERPDERP", expected output is a string literal gleaned from that (the end result of this code is supposed to be a rail fence cipher, but that's aside the point), output is nothing but a blank interpreter line.

Comment: Probably while loop never finishes. This can happen in case  `if counter == steps` is not True. Check the step value and counter .

Comment: Your loops are all messed up, either the while or the for can be factored out.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the starting value of `steps` its possible for `counter` and `steps` to never be equal, which means `conversion_string` is never altered, so it is always shorter than `string_to_convert` and the loop never ends.

A naive example is, let `steps=-1`, since `counter` starts at `0` and increments, and `steps` always decrements, they will never be equal.

---

Actually, on further inspection, if `steps` is less than `len(string_to_convert)` this will *always* end in an infinite loop.

Consider:

```
steps=2
string_to_convert="Python"
```

1. The first iteration of the for loop will iterate `counter` to 2 and fetch the "t"; now `steps = 1`, `conversion_string="t"`
2. Next for loop will iterate `counter` to 1, fetch the "y"; now `steps = 0`, `conversion_string="ty"`
3. for loop iterates `counter` to 0, fetch the "P"; now `steps = -1`, `conversion_string="tyP"`
4. Now, `steps = -1`, `counter` can never equal it, for loop ends without changing `conversion_string`.
5. Step 4 repeats while decreasing `steps` without any ability to quit the while loop.

Thus, why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Huh.  I always thought the interpreter could catch infinite loops like that.

Comment: Nope, sometimes infinite loops are useful.